# How to call class constant value in this case

Tags: php

suppose i need to get value which is formed dynamically like

```
StaticClass::chatincon
```

is formed using dyanmic part $aa

```
$aa = icon;
echo StaticClass::chat{$aa}; // not working
```

what's the correct way to preferably without use of eval() // as eval r subjected to eval injection

Answer (score 1):

```
constant("StaticClass::chat$aa")
```

http://php.net/constant

<sub>And constants aren't "called", they're "accessed" if anything.</sub>

Comment: how its differnet from eval ??
is this safe to use... like eval is not recomnded ?

Comment: It explicitly looks up a constant by name. It does not blindly evaluate code. `constant` is a function to access a constant given a string, because there's no other way to do this. `constant('exec("rm -rf /");')` will do nothing dangerous, but `eval('exec("rm -rf /");')` will.

Answer (score 1):

Use function constant() (as in http://www.php.net/constant) i.e :

```
constant('StaticClass::chat'. $aa)
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `constant` . The syntax is

```
constant ( string $name )
```

It should be

```
constant('StaticClass::chat'. $aa)
```

Comment: There's no "`constant` keyword".